# understanding crop hints by google vision ai

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vision

i am trying google vision api for crop hints and the output results are like below

i am having hard time understanding these crop hints to be able to use on my image. so first thing is the empty vertices. what are they? also i was hoping all the pairs will have a x and y value to draw on 2D space. but some has only x and some has only y.

finally how should i get my final image? i am using firebase cloud function which is a nodejs with typescript to operate on my original image to get final image?

ideally i want this to happen on device but it seems there are no cordova plugins yet to run autoML on device to capture and crop the image as soon as prominent object is detected.

is there any other cordova plugin that can help to capture the promiment image auto capture as soon as it is visible in camera?

````
{
  "cropHintsAnnotation": {
    "cropHints": [
      {
        "boundingPoly": {
          "vertices": [
            {},
            {
              "x": 2499
            },
            {
              "x": 2499,
              "y": 3132
            },
            {
              "y": 3132
            }
          ]
        },
        "confidence": 0.79999995,
        "importanceFraction": 0.98999995
      },
      {
        "boundingPoly": {
          "vertices": [
            {},
            {
              "x": 2499
            },
            {
              "x": 2499,
              "y": 2532
            },
            {
              "y": 2532
            }
          ]
        },
        "confidence": 0.79999995,
        "importanceFraction": 0.91999996
      },
      {
        "boundingPoly": {
          "vertices": [
            {},
            {
              "x": 2499
            },
            {
              "x": 2499,
              "y": 2098
            },
            {
              "y": 2098
            }
          ]
        },
        "confidence": 0.79999995,
        "importanceFraction": 0.81
      }
    ]
  }               
}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

A missing x or y means that its value is 0.